# Подправьте создание папки

Tags: c#

Не получается в директории создать файл, и так и много как по разному пробую создать внутри папки файл, ничего не получается, помогите, пожалуйста.
Дело вот как:
Создаю папку в AppData если её нет, папка создается, в эту же папку пытаюсь добавить файл `oject_test.txt`
Пока-что без успешно...
Тыкните, пожалуйста, что я делаю не правильно при этом всём...

```
        string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        string specificFolder = Path.Combine(folder, "Папка приложения");
        if (!Directory.Exists(specificFolder))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(specificFolder);
            string path = Path.Combine(folder, "Папка приложения");
            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                File.Create("oject_test.txt");
            }
            LoadBlock.Text = path;
        }
```

Comment: Ну пожалуйста, будьте внимательней, ну научитесь вы думать сами то. Вы сделали `path`, которая содержит путь до директории, далее проверяете "а есть ли эта директория", если ее нету, то вы создаете файл `oject_test.txt` в корне рабочей директории (по умолчанию это корень приложения), ибо вы не указали путь...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очень простые ошибки, ради которых не стоит создавать вопрос на StackOverflow

```csharp
string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
string specificFolder = Path.Combine(folder, "Папка приложения");
if (!Directory.Exists(specificFolder))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(specificFolder);
}
string fileName = "oject_test.txt";
string path = Path.Combine(specificFolder, fileName);
if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
    {
        // здесь можно что-то записать в файл
    }
}
LoadBlock.Text = path;
```

Comment: Я согласен, но, это ещё не всё, я хотел бы уточнить, а это нормально что папка создается по такому пути: `Имя ПК\AppData\Roaming\YourFolderThis` у всех пользователей которые будут использоваться приложение, будет такой же путь? Ибо в этой папке будут настройки и т.д

Comment: @L1onelY зависит от значения переменной окружения `%APPDATA%`. Например, если система установлена на диске D:, и Application Data находится там, то будет создана там.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста подсказать ещё с вот этим:                 `string folder_1 = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
                string folder_2 = Path.Combine(folder_1, "YourProjectTest");
                string folder_3 = Path.Combine(folder_2, "TestProject.exe");

                NameLaunchers.Text = folder_3;
                if (File.Exists(folder_3))
                {
                    File.Delete("TestProject.exe");
                }`
Не удаляет файл, пишет почему-то ошибка...

Comment: @L1onelY `File.Delete(folder_3)`, вам явно не хватает внимательности

Comment: Это да, я капец запутался, каша просто в голове образовалась... Извините